# Browser can read data but curl not

Tags: php, curl

I tried many times by php curl to get data from this url http://img.somedomain.com:1500/diveSpots/all

But didn't get any result. Browser can read the data but not curl. I have checked CURL is enabled and curl can get data from other sites. Can someone tell me what is the issue? If you need any more information, please ask me. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code

```
<?php

    $ch= curl_init("http://somedomain.com:1500/images/numberOfImagesFor/vXcuZ71E61/");
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36");
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($result);
```

?>

google.se works well. and other url also working well. I have tried form my shell also and it is working. From Browser and terminal both can fetch the results but php curl not. I have also tried with shell_exec command but still no result. 
Can you tell me what is the actual problem?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Maybe User Agent? Maybe cookies? Maybe referer?

Comment: Change the url to http://google.se and you will se that there is nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: Without a real URL it is hard to investigate your issue.

Comment: img.1planet.mobi:1500/diveSpots/all

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me (took a while though, like 5 sec). Could you try it?

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', 'on' );
error_reporting( E_ALL );


$ch= curl_init("http://img.1planet.mobi:1500/diveSpots/all");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36");
$result=curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Did you echo out ´$sResponse´?

Comment: Yes, but browser is loading and then shows blank page. Nothing is coming